# Using a java library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to use [this](https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/) java library in my Android Studio project. It's a Java library, not an Android library. How would I import this java library into my Android Studio project so that I can use it in my Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Add the .jar to your app/libs directory.

You should already have this in your build.gradle file, but if not you'll need to add it:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download code from Here: https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/source/browse/

And set `.jar` file into build path